# Icons of m4v files missing after El Capitan update

Tags: icon

After El Capitan update (from Yosemite) icons of m4v files (quicktime player icons) are missing. Instead of it they are blank.

Blank icon:

[image]

Must be:

[image]

Any suggestions how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility out there that does about all of the cleaning operations on a Mac O/S system, it's called Onyx and can be found on MacUpdate or thru your favorite search engine.

Go to the automate tab, check everything and let it run. Reboot when done. That should clean things up (caches, permissions, etc.) and is likely to fix this issue. It has for me.

Failing that my only other suggestion is to apply the latest [combo update for El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1859?locale=en_US). Combo updates often fix a multitude of strange issues.

Comment: No, no luck with OnyX. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately combo update didn't help. Anyway thank you for your help. I think that the only way to fix it is to completely reinstall OS. Or maybe Apple will fix it later :)